# How to get count of files based on file content search in MarkLogic using xquery

Tags: marklogic

I want to get a count of all xml files from a certain database in MarkLogic using XQuery, based on some values within the content of the file.
The content can be any value from any fields of the XML structure.

example:

There are 5 similar structure of xml files in Database where value of one of the XML fields `<SubmissionUser>` is different in all files.

```
    <SystemRef>22000041</SystemRef>
    <DateCreated>2022-09-06T19:07:46.3492849+01:00</DateCreated>
    <TimeSaved>240</TimeSaved>
    <Production>true</Production>
    <Partner>CGI</Partner>
    <MessageType>Invoice</MessageType>
    <Fail>false</Fail>
    <ManyReasons/>
    <SubmissionUser>Rashmita</SubmissionUser>
    <InternalBusinessUnit>Finance</InternalBusinessUnit>
```

I want to get the count of those files among the 5 files whose *SubmissionUser* is Rashmita and *InternalBusinessUnit* is Finance.
How can I achieve that using xquery in MarkLogic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cts:element-value-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query) to search for documents that have a particular element with a particular value, and combine the criteria for those two elements with [`cts:and-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:and-query) in a [`cts:search()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search).

If you know the results are going to be relatively small, you can `count()` how many items are returned from the `cts:search()`. However, if you have a really large database and can potentially return millions of items, you may find that `count()` can be slow.

Since this is a relatively straightforward query and there shouldn't be an issue with false-positives and index resolution. Therefore, it's faster and more efficient to use [`xdmp:estimate()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:estimate) instead of `count()`:

```
xdmp:estimate(
  cts:search(doc(), 
    cts:and-query(( 
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("SubmissionUser"), "Rashmita"),
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("InternalBusinessUnit"), "Finance")
    )) 
  )
)
```

You could also use [`cts:uris()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uris) with the same query criteria and count the URIs:

```
count(
  cts:uris("", (),
    cts:and-query(( 
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("SubmissionUser"), "Rashmita"),
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("InternalBusinessUnit"), "Finance")
    ))
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks I have used cts:search() and it worked :-)